# 1.2 GHz Cloverleaf Antenna tolerance

Tags: antenna, video, tolerance

I'm working on building my own Cloverleaf antennas, to work at 1.2 GHz, for the video system on my Quadcopter. At this frequency, what kind of tolerance am I looking at in terms of the length of the wire and the various geometric angles before I lose the advantage of this type of antenna? The calculator I used to find the length spit out a number in millimeters with, like, 8 decimal points after it, but after converting to inches, using a tape measure to measure it out, and trying to do the whole shebang in my dorm room bathroom (no hate on this please, it's fireproof I swear!), I only have about 1/8" - 1/16" accuracy. Is this enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IANARFEng... but

Wavelength of 1.2GHz in air is 25cm.

Often tolerances of λ/10 are acceptable (which is about an inch), so I'd think 1/8" would be OK.